# Bootstrap 4 striped table - add row and redraw stripes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table striped using `Bootstrap 4`. I programmatically add a row to the top of the table, and it throws the odd/even row coloring off. How do I re-run the CSS formatting?

My JS:

```
$clonedRow = $('tr#row-template-new').clone();
$clonedRow.attr('id', 'row-new');

if (!$clonedRow) {
   return false;
}

$('#editor-table tbody').prepend($clonedRow);
$('#row-new').fadeIn('slow');
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="editor-table">
    .....
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always remove the table-striped class, then re-add the table-striped class after the adding of the new row. I also removed the row-new ID since you will have duplicate IDs after adding more  than one row.

```
$clonedRow = $('tr#row-template-new').clone();
$clonedRow.attr('id', 'row-new');

if (!$clonedRow) {
   return false;
}
$('#editor-table tbody').prepend($clonedRow);    
$('#row-new').fadeIn('slow').removeAttr("id");
$('#editor-table').removeClass("table-striped").addClass("table-striped");
```

Comment: Hi @iamvain2 it was a great suggestion but for some reason it is not working. Imy inserted row remains grey.